# Iterate through values in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, cumulative-sum

I want to iterate through a column with numerical values, and sum the values as I go, and then return the respective ID's and the sum so far. All of these should be based on ascending order of date

My table looks like

```
id | money | date
---------- | ----------
01 | 2300  | 01/03/2017
02 | 35    | 01/01/2017
03 | 70    | 01/02/2017
```

So my result would be -

```
id | money
----------
02 | 35
03 | 105
01 | 2405
```

From there, I want to only return the id's with total sum less than or equal to a value, so lets say that value was 2400, my table result would be -

```
id 
---
02 
03
```

I wrote a query -

```
SELECT id 
FROM tableName
WHERE 2400 >=
    (SELECT id, SUM(money)
    FROM tableName
    WHERE money IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY id) WHERE EXISTS
        (SELECT * 
        FROM tableName
        WHERE date ASC));
```

I understand that I am simply summing money , and then comparing one integer against that number, but how do I do this dynamically, and in one query? Will I have to make a for loop?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You could use the window variant of the `sum` function to get a running total:

```
SELECT id
FROM   (SELECT id, SUM(money) OVER (ORDER BY date ASC) AS money
        FROM   monies) t 
WHERE  money <= 2400
```